# How to refresh Scapy configuration after importing it?

Tags: python, scapy

I am using scapy.all.conf.route.routes in order to get some network info (especially gateway and IP for a specific NIC), the problem is that I import Scapy via "from scapy.all import *" at the beginning of the script but the same script does an ifup of my NIC later. If seems that once the module has been loaded, Scapy does not refresh its config and scapy.all.conf.route.routes still does not contain the info about the NIC I just started via ifup.
The entire project makes extensive use of Scapy so I would like to use Scapy here as well but I am still curious about other options as well.

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
conf.route.resync()
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to select your answer.